# Can I soak my helmet in water?

Tags: helmets

I have a lot of sweat in all straps and padding in my helmet.

When i ride in heavy rain the salt from my sweat starts dripping down my face. Its very unpleasant especially if it goes in my mouth.

How can I get rid of this salt?

Comment: how old is the helmet? i see a lot of companies recommend replacing them after 3-4 years.  maybe just buy a new one?

Comment: probably 3-4 years old. It seems wasteful to shell out 40-50 bucks though

Comment: PS: Despite what your "friends"/girlfriend/wife says, remove head from helmet before soaking helmet.

Comment: As for the question ("can I soak..."), it already happens when you ride in rain.

Comment: Just bring it in the shower with you after a ride. Rinse with lots of water. Hang dry. Done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The helmet itself is (probably) polysterene foam inner and a harder plastic shell, it's fine to wash this in water and some mild detergent (eg dish soap)

You can try and wash the straps in hot soapy water.

The problem is the pads. Usually washing the pads means that they come unglued, the surface layers separate from the inner cushion part. All you can do is keep the extra ones you get to size a new helmet and swap them.

I don't know if pro racing type helmets come with multiple sets of replaceable straps and pads - but they should.

Answer (score 5):

You should refer to the manual for the helmet for cleaning instructions. Usually it will say to use mild soap and water.

A helmet will not be damaged by water, but **don't use heat to dry it** afterwards as this can destroy your helmet. Also, if the padding is removable then you might be able to get replacement pads.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to wash, even submerge, your helmet in water, with perhaps a dash of mild detergent.  Use no other solvents or additives.  If submerging, agitate *very* slowly, since the force of water against pads or other loosely-attached elements can be quite strong.

Dry by draining thoroughly and placing in a slightly warm place (not somewhere where you could not sit comfortably for at least a few minutes -- high heat can kill a helmet).  Expect it to take 2-3 days to completely dry if submerged.  DO NOT put the helmet "away" (in a bag or box, in an enclosed area, etc) before it is thoroughly dry.

If pads are removable, remove them and wash separately, but washing with the helmet should not harm the pads (or their adhesive) any more than riding in the rain or sweating in the helmet.

Comment: I'd go this way, too, so +1. Besides that, I think that if it is still a bit moist, you could make it dry by simply riding it.